# SIFT- how to find similarity in more than 2 images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I know how to compare 2 images with SIFT (in matlab) but what if I have to find the similarity in between multiple images. Let for instance, I have 30 Images. How can I use SIFT to say that 10 of them have 30% match and 5 of them have 95% match? 
I can use clustering but before doing that I need some kind of value on which I can apply clustering technique.
I have been bothered by this question for quiet a few hours. So friends if you know please do help me.

thanks

Comment: Consider the bag of words model.  See my reply here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357352/euclidean-distance-in-sift/8549874#8549874][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357352/euclidean-distance-in-sift/8549874#8549874

Answer (score 1):

Consider SIFT-ing by comparison to the average image, then cluster by similar amounts/locations of difference across the image. Then, you can compare the image clusters to the cluster-averages.